# How to run cpplint.py for all files in a directory on Windows batch?

Tags: cpplint

My current script is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set TargetDir=%1
set FilesAll=

for /r %TargetDir% %%f in (*.h *.cc) do (
  set FilesAll=!FilesAll! %%f
)

python.exe cpplint.py %FilesAll%
```

Is there any better way to do this job?